# Setting custom ID on signalR core start

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, signalr

I am building a app that involves a 1:1 customer and administrator session.
I'm using opentok to connect a customer with an administrator and creating a unique ID for their session. 
There will be multiple customer:administrator sessions but each session should be unique.

I am using React and asp.net core 3.

I want to be able to have a private Signal R connection between the customer and the administrator. There is no authorization setup, its all based on a Unique ID they will be given in their query string.

Currently I am connecting to Signal R in React like this:

```
import { HubConnectionBuilder } from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import config from "config.js";

export default function useSignalR() {
    const [hubConnection, setHubConnection] = useState(null);  

    useEffect(() => {
        //ideally ill supply the connection a guid here
        let connectionBuilder = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(config.signalRServerUrl)
            .build();

        setHubConnection(connectionBuilder);
        connectionBuilder.start()
            .then(() => console.log("signalr connection started"))
            .catch((err) => console.log("Error while establishihng connection ", err));
    }, []);

    return hubConnection;
}
```

the administrator and customer are using the same function to connect to the asp.net core signal R hub, which currently just looks like this:

```
public class PhotoHub : Hub
{
    public async Task TakeSnapShot()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("takeSnapShot");
    }
}
```

I imagine it will look something like this:

**pseudo code only**

```
 //in javascript connection
  let connectionBuilder = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withProperty(uniqueId)   //pseudo code
        .withUrl(config.signalRServerUrl)
        .build();
```

<-- on server below -->

```
public class PhotoHub : Hub
{
    public async Task TakeSnapShot(uniqueId)
    {
       var clientsInSession = Clients.where(customId == uniqueId); //pseudo code  
       foreach (var client in clientsInSession){
           await client.SendAsync("takeSnapShot");   //pseudo code
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR already provide unique connection id when you connect to the hub using this code in your hub

```
    public string GetConnectionId()
    {
        return Context.ConnectionId;
    }
```

So you can call like this

```
 var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/connectionHub").build();

        connection.start().then(function () {
            console.log("connected");

            connection.invoke('getConnectionId')
                .then(function (connectionId) {
                    console.log(connectionId)
                }).catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));;

        });
```

Comment: I guess here I could include my session id with the connection id, like "GetConectionId(string sessionId).. then store a global static dictionary of sesionId->ConnectionId..

Comment: yes you can do that but store the connection id using session storage is good approach